# CoreUI free bootstrap template not working

Tags: core-ui

I recently downloaded CoreUI bootstrap free template. I tried launching index.html , but the UI was so terrible.

CSS was linked to css/style.css , but no css folder was present , only scss was available. I tried updating the href to point ot style.scss, still no use.

Can anybodu point me to the right source ? Support from CoreUi is only for Licensed version, so unabel to directly check with CoreUI guys.

Below is the folder structure post download :

[image]

CSS href (only available css reference in index.html):

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="node_modules/@coreui/chartjs/dist/css/coreui-chartjs.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in cmd line while in the installation folder:

```
npm run serve
```

Comment: after running the above cmd, you will get the dist folder with CSS file

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use CDN, add below code to your HTML pages

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/js/coreui.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the documentation of using core UI with CDN https://coreui.io/docs/getting-started/download/#coreui-cdn

Answer (score 0):

Installation instruction can be found on admin template Github:

https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template#installation